# Program won't close fully after closing

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a problem with a project. After I close my program it won't start anymore because it is still half running in the background.

Sideinfos:

I use threads to asynchronously send refreshing values to other clients via multicast.

How can I stop the threads, so they won't run in the background and I can restart the program?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start a thread, you can just set the `IsBackground` property to true so that it does not survive the death of the other threads.

```
var thread = new Thread(SendAndReceive);
thread.IsBackground = true;
thread.Start();
```